# Why consecutive calls to SetForegroundWindow doesn't work?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am writing a small utility program to manipulate windows, what I want to do is bring two windows to the foreground one at a time, I looked up the doc, there is an API, SetForegroundWindow.

It works if I only call it once. With two consecutive calls, it doesn't work as expected. What I expected is the behavior when I click an icon in the taskbar, then click another. The code looks like this,

```
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd1);
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd2);
```

Why doesn't it work? How should I get the expected behavior.

Comment: There are a lot of documented restrictions on how `SetForegroundWindow()` can be used.  You are obviously not meeting those restrictions

Comment: A mini, complete and reproducible sample and detailed information (any error? or description of the behavior.) of "it doesn't work as expected" are more helpful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

The API works as advertised. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow):

> Brings the thread that created the specified window into the foreground and activates the window.

In other words, it changes the foreground thread. Given your use case this implies changing the foreground process as well.

Further down, the API lists some [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow#remarks):

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - [...]

After the first successful call to `SetForegroundWindow`, the calling process is no longer the foreground process. Subsequent calls will fail (unless you have requested special permissions).

---

Mandatory reading: [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083).